# what type of data for a percentage column in sql server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm working in ASP.NET and i want to import a Excel Sheet to my table in SQL Server.
The problem is that one column of my Excel has a percentage type (example : 25%). Do you have a solution to stock this percentage value in my table in SQL Server ?

I post my code if you want :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
                OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

                // Feuil1 est la première page du fichier Excel
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]", OleDbcon);
                OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                OleDbcon.Open();
                DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                // configuration de la chaîne de connexion de SQL Server
                string con_str = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=projetDGCS;Integrated Security=True";

                // On copie dans SQL Server 
                SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con_str);
                // On mets le nom de la table de destination
                bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "reponse";
                bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
                OleDbcon.Close();
                // On a stocké le fichier Excel dans le dossier "temp" et on le supprime après 
                Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"))), File.Delete);
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                Label1.Text = "Insertion réussie !";

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has no percentage type for fields. It has a percentage FORMATTING for NUMERIC fields - the same your application can apply. 0.01 = 1% (at least my school did teach me that).

This is very objective - you can store a percentage value either in any numeric field. How you format it and whether you use for example a tinyint (1 = 1%) is totally up to you as programmer.